# increment counter after piping in Bash

Tags: bash, shell

I am finding all files from / and for each file found, I am incrementing a counter. My issue is once the while loop is exited, the counter resets to zero.

```
i=0
find / 2> /dev/null | \
while read l 
do
[ -f $l ] && echo $l
i=$(( ++i ))
done
echo $i
```

Comment: An other way to count files `find / -type f 2>/dev/null|awk '{i++; print $0}END{print i}'`

Answer (score 4):

The pipe (`|`) spawns a subprocess to run the `while` loop; any changes made in the `while` loop (eg, modifying variables) is lost when the `while` loop completes (ie, the subprocess exits); if the `while` loop is just writing to stdout, or to a file, then the `| while ...` construct is 'ok' (ie, the output to stdout, or the file, does not 'disappear').

You can perform the same steps without generating a subprocess by instead using process substitution in which case the assignments made within the `while` loop are maintained after exiting the `while` loop, eg:

```
i=0

while read l 
do
    [ -f $l ] && echo $l
    i=$(( ++i ))
done < <(find / 2> /dev/null)           # process substitution

echo $i
```

Comment: and `find / -type f` instead of `[ -f $l ]`

Comment: @ufopilot yeah but, OP's logic is keeping a count of *all* files regardless of type while only `echo`'ing the names of type `-f` files

Comment: i see.. maybe that's what he wants

Comment: Why do these two methods give a different value of the count variable? What type of file does ```find / -type f ``` return ?

Comment: run the 2 `find` commands by themselves, collect (and sort) the results, then compare the results; your `find` is going to pull up 'regular' files, directories, symlinks, named pipes, etc thus leading to a larger value in `i`; the `find -type f` will only return 'regular' files and thus a smaller value in `i`; ultimately *you* need to decide what it is you're looking to `find` ('course running your `find` on the root directory is questionable, ie, why are you scanning the host's entire filesystem(s)?)

Comment: Thank you. It now makes sense. I am testing a backup script.